# What to Use in NSCollectionView's SupplementaryElementKind String Value in Swift 4.2

Tags: cocoa, nscollectionview, swift4.2

**Prior to Swift 4.2**, I could create an `NSCollectionView` header like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: NSCollectionView.SupplementaryElementKind, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSView {
  let view = collectionView.makeSupplementaryView(ofKind: .sectionHeader, withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "Header"), for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! Header

  view.sectionTitle.stringValue = collectionSections[indexPath.section]
  return view
}
```

If I remember right, the `.sectionHeader` was from an `enum` from `NSCollectionView.SupplementaryElementKind`. But [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionview/supplementaryelementkind) say `NSCollectionView.SupplementaryElementKind` is a `String`.

That leaves me with updated **Swift 4.2** code like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: NSCollectionView.SupplementaryElementKind, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSView {
  let view = collectionView.makeSupplementaryView(ofKind: "?????", withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "Header"), for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! Header

  view.sectionTitle.stringValue = collectionSections[indexPath.section]
  return view
}
```

I'm unclear on what I should include for the `ofKind` parameter (`String`). What would that string correspond to? I don't see anything else to associate it with in my xib file.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. You just pass in the `kind` parameter from the `makeSupplementaryView` delegate method it lives inside.

```
let view = collectionView.makeSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "Header"), for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! Header
```